# Properly cancel an image download in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, image, download

I have a set of `Image` elements that I use to download pictures. All the pictures have to be downloaded, but I wish to download the picture the user is looking at in the first place. If the user changes the viewed picture, I wish to cancel the downloads in progress to get the viewed picture as fast as possible.

To start a download I write: `myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(theUri);`.

How should I cancel it?

- `myImage.Source = null;` ?
- act on the BitmapImage ?
- a better solution ?

I don't wish to download the picture by code to keep the benefit of the browser cache.

Comment: Why do you believe that using code would lose the benefit of the browser cache?

Comment: by "downloading by code" I meant downloading the picture bytes using a webservice and assigning it to the Image element. This could be the subject of another question, but what technique would you use to control the download sequesce by preserving the browser cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely doable -- I just tested it to make sure.  Here is a quick class you can try:

```
public partial class Page : UserControl
{
    private WebClient m_oWC;
    public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_oWC = new WebClient();
        m_oWC.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(m_oWC_OpenReadCompleted);
    }

    void StartDownload(string sImageURL)
    {
        if (m_oWC.IsBusy)
        {
            m_oWC.CancelAsync();
        }
        m_oWC.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(sImageURL));
    }

    void m_oWC_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage oBMI = new BitmapImage();
        oBMI.SetSource(e.Result);
        imgMain.Source = oBMI;
    }
}
```

This works just like you wanted (I tested it).  Everytime you call StartDownload with the URL of an image (presumably whenever a user clicks to the next image) if there is a current download in progress it is canceled.  The broswer cache is also definitely being used (I verified with fiddler), so cached images are loaded ~ instantly.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the WebClient class being actually an access to the browser download functionality. I trust you and validate the answer right now, even if I need some time to adapt it to our project. Thanks.